# Как реализовать работу ВК бота и в ЛС, и в беседах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот, long-poll

Необходимо написать бота, который умеет работать и в ЛС, и в беседах. Поначалу я использовал вот такой код:

```
import vk_api
from vars import main_token
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method ('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

def peer_sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method ('messages.send', {'peer_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

# Авторизация как сообщество
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        if event.to_me and event.from_user:

            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id

            if msg in ('привет','hello','hi','start','старт','команды'):
                sender(id, commands)

            elif msg == 'тест':
                sender(id, 'Тест прошел успешно, бот работает!')

            else:
                sender(id, 'К сожалению, я не знаю такой команды... ')

        elif event.to_me and event.from_chat:

            idz = event.peer_id
            msg = event.text.lower()

            if msg == 'тест':
                peer_sender(idz, 'Тест прошел успешно, бот работает в чате!')
```

Этот код хорошо работал в ЛС, но совсем не реагировал на сообщения в беседе (админка выдана )
После я выяснил, что при авторизации как сообщество нужно использовать Vk**Bot**LongPoll

Я создал другой вариант кода:

```
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

vk_session = VkApi(token=main_token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'id сообщества')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method ('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        vk.messages.send(random_id=get_random_id(), peer_id=event.obj['peer_id'], message='Test message')

    elif event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_user:
        sender(id, 'Test message')
```

К сожалению, этот код работает в беседе, но не работает в ЛС

Отсюда, в итоге, вопрос: **как запустить бота в ЛС и беседе одновременно?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отправки сообщения в ЛС, используй такой же метод, как и для бесед. В данном случаи разницы нет, так как peer_id это id диалога